# ¿Como cargar un mapa de google earth en Q-GIS?

Tags: openlayers

Mi objetivo es integrar el mapa de google maps en QGIS, instale el plugin de open layers, para mapear unas charcas de carácter temporal, pero estoy un poco perdido de los pasos que hay que seguir, un saludo.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una vez instalado, encuentras los layers de Google maps tal como aparecen en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay que destacar que al cargar el layer de Google Satellite, el SRC del proyecto cambia a EPSG 3857, por lo que puede que algunas capas se distorsionen en el proceso de establecer el SRC 'al vuelo'.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero incluyas el plugin «QuickMapServices». Puedes revisar el siguiente link para poder incluirlo en QGIS.
https://mappinggis.com/2016/09/plugin-quickmapservices-capas-base-de-google-landsat-openstreetmap-para-qgis/

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder; pero dejar solo un enlace es considerado baja calidad porque si se 'rompe' el enlace se pierde la respuesta. Te invito a revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Si utilizas alguna version 3.x.x el plugin no estara en la base de complementos como en versiones anteriores. Yo encontre solo la base de OpenStreets en el panel **Navegador** dentro de la opcion **XYZTiles**. Espero que les sirva el dato.
Saludos!